# How to open Tailwind Slide-over inside a container

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, headless-ui

I am trying to open tailwind slide-over inside of a container instead of the browser window but I can't figure out the correct positioning
here is the example https://play.tailwindcss.com/MdY5WoOq5w

Please help me understand how to position the slide-over correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I am using daisy.ui for drawer. It’s easy to use https://daisyui.com/components/drawer/ I hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check this Tailwind Play link.

Heads up I have used some eye hurting colors. These colors helps in working on the layout.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/k02XZ01a7E

A little inspiration was taken from https://layoutsfortailwind.lalokalabs.dev/ui/layout-drawer/

Points to improve on.

- The h-screen of the drawer overflows the screen height.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. but I don't see any relevance between these examples! My question has a clear point. To open the slide-over inside the blue container.

Comment: Hi, If you see my example. I have opened a slideover on the right hand side. With the words "Settings Content" You may follow that example and try to achieve the same for your container. If not let me know I shall try and do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).